# Error while inserting dataframe into oracle table using python

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am querying an oracle table (Table1) into pandas dataframe and then truing to insert the same into another oracle table(Table2) with the same table/column definition.

I am also changing the 'object' datatypes into VARCHAR in my code to avoid CLOB and speed up the insert.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import types

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@dbname')

df = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM TABLE1',con=conn)

dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max())
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}

df.to_sql('TABLE2', conn, index=False, if_exists='append', dtype=dtyp, chunksize=10**4)
```

The primary key column ACCOUNT_ID is VARCHAR2(100) in both source and target tables. I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: ACCOUNT_ID (VARCHAR(8)) not a string
```

Please help me.

Comment: If you give the error, someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Can you provide the structure for TABLE1 and TABLE2 and the contents of TABLE1?